# While loop even count

Tags: java, while-loop

my problem is the following. If I input number 2, the code counts it as an odd number.

Remainder for 2 / 2 = 0 so the error doesn't make sense.

Below is the program:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Ohjelma {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Tänne voit kirjoittaa ohjelmakoodia. Ohjelmasi voit ajaa
    // valitsemalla menusta Run->Run File tai painamalla Shift+F6
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Type numbers: ");
    int number = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());
    int sum = 0;
    int many = 0;
    double average = 0;
    int even = 0;
    int odd = 0;

    while (number != -1) {
        System.out.println("Type numbers: ");
        sum = sum + number;
        number = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());
        many++;
        average = (double)sum / many;
        if (number%2 == 0) {
            even++;
        } else {
            odd++;
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Thank you and see you later!");
    System.out.println("The sum is " + sum);
    System.out.println("How many numbers: " + many);
    System.out.println("Average: " + average);
    System.out.println("Even numbers: " + even);
    System.out.println("Odd numbers: " + odd);
```

Comment: This is probably homework, so I'll prompt you with this: print out the values of number, sum, many, average, even, and odd at the bottom of your loop. That way you can make sure the variables have the correct values after each iteration.

Comment: Please, please consider using [Scanner.nextInt()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt(int)) or catch the `NumberFormatException` that `parseInt` can throw. This kind of omissions make my eyes bleed.

Comment: I know other kind of answered you, but it is not clear what your issue is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that for the critical part of your program it largely ignores the first input, apart from adding it to the running `sum`. You want to recast it like this:

```
Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
int sum = 0;
int many = 0;
double average = 0;
int even = 0;
int odd = 0;

do {
    System.out.println("Type numbers: ");
    number = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());
    if (number == -1)
        break;
    sum = sum + number;
    many++;
    average = (double)sum / many;
    if (number%2 == 0) {
        even++;
    } else {
        odd++;
    }
} while (true);
```

This will certainly processes even and odd numbers correctly.

Comment: @SpaceRock you're welcome! Please do click the tick to mark as accepted answer if it was helpful (gives you some rep points as well).

Answer (score 0):

Your code reads the second line of input into `number` before it checks whether `number` is odd ... and -1 is odd.